# How can I force the phone to have a fixed IP address on 2GHz and 5GHz WiFi?

Tags: wi-fi, ip-address

I am running an FTP server on my Samsung Galaxy Note 20. On my router, I have given it a fixed IP address based on its MAC address on a 5GHz network. But when the phone connects on 2GHz, it has a different MAC address.  My router refuses to give the same IP address to two devices, even if only one is connected.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would disable MAC address randomization for both Wifi entries that belong to your Wifi router.

Then your device is seen by the router as one device with one MAC address.

You can do so by editing the Wifi entry, open the "Advanced options" section and there change the Privacy setting to "Use device MAC".

[image]

Comment: I had set the IP address on both networks, on the phone to static.  This was working but I wasnt happy with it.  Above is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

While I prefer the accepted answer, there is another way to do this.

Set the static IP address on both 5G and 2G Wifi settings.  This works well, but I prefer the IP address to be set by the router/DHCP.

[image]